# CMS Home Page appears below custom Default Home on one store view

Tags: cms, multistore, frontend, store-view

I want to set a different home page to route to a cms page for one of the stores only.

I set up my default Home landing page in System > Configuration > Web > Default Pages and setting CMS Home Page to another page, while excluding the home page in CMS > Pages for this store view, but the home page is appearing below my custom landing page.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized that the blocks from the home page that are appearing were set to all store views, so I excluded them by editing each block to hide from CMS > Static Blocks.

Edit: I also found some in the template files for this theme, so I had to comment them out for the specific store view.

Comment: If this is the solution please flag it as so. Otherwise I advice you to move this comment to your main question text

Comment: you'll have to wait 3 days :)

Comment: The world of Magento development is hectic, thanks for the reminder :)